# How do I modify the components in a GroupLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

Well, I'm using GroupLayout to place components. Here is a code.

```
groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(10)
                            .addComponent(BrandName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(brand, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(price, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(rugType, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(materialType, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(rugAmount, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addContainerGap()
                            .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(okButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addContainerGap(115, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(11)
                    .addComponent(BrandName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 24, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(brand, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(price, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(rugType, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(materialType, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(rugAmount, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(okButton))
                    .addContainerGap(187, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
```

Now I need to add new components after clicking OK-button. How can I modify groupLayout?
Is there .getVerticalGroup method or smth like that? Need help.

Comment: Read "Runtime Changes to Your GUI" in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html)

Comment: Why are you using GroupLayout by hand? IDE's are most suited to generating this code for you (Netbeans for example)

Comment: don't forget to add a new JButton to the both groups

Comment: I don't use GroupLayout by hand. But to layout after click, I need to do it by hand, I suppose.

Comment: As I understood there is only 2 methods. To replace components and to change visibility. But how can I add new components? With help of this two methods?

Comment: *"Is there .getVerticalGroup method"* This is where you need to grab control of the code form the IDE and make the vertical group a named attribute to which you keep a reference.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As says @maress, you can use object reference, e. g. like this:

```
GroupLayout.Group horizontal =
        groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(10)
                        .addComponent(BrandName, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(brand, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(price, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(rugType, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(materialType, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(rugAmount, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(okButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 55, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(115, Short.MAX_VALUE));

groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(horizontal);
```

And after that, use the horizontal object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to maintain a reference to the group you want edit

Comment: How can I maintain a reference to VerticalGroup for example?

Answer (score 0):

Use *NetBeans IDE* to create your layout, just by dragging and dropping the *SWING* elements over the `Jframe` in the design mode.

If you want to change the layout at *run-time* you can do one of the following:

1. Generalize by investigating the generated code by the *IDE* to know on
   what `components` to add and how
2. Create a test design `Jframe` to generate the code, and use that code at
   run-time (by changing/copying/pasting to the needed locations)

Use  `groupLayout.getVerticalGroup()` and `groupLayout.getHorizontalGroup()` and use their methods on the returned object to remove or new components.

Comment: I'm using eclipse plugin. It does the same.

Comment: I'm investigating the generated code, but there is only set Vertical/Horizontal group. I'd like to know, how to modify this groups?

Comment: Use  `groupLayout.getVerticalGroup()` and `groupLayout.getHorizontalGroup()` and use their methods on the returned object to remove or new components.

Comment: Ok, I used this methods like this. groupLayout.getVerticalGroup();
But there is a mistake that this method is not visible. How can I solve this problem?